# Why is live view so dark when I'm shooting with strobes?

Tags: product-photography, live-view, godox, strobes

We are having a setup where we use two strobes to photograph.
When I switch to live view the image is incredibly dark due to the camera settings and the amount of ambient light. Since I want to use a strobe I've set the ISO to 200 and the shutter speed to 1/200 to work with the strobe settings.

If I switch to a higher ISO or use a slower shutter speed then I can see the image in live view, however, when the strobe flashes the output image is overexposed.

Everything is in full manual mode.

Gear used:

- Camera: Nikon Z6 II
- Lens: Nikkor 24-70 mm f/4
- Strobe: Godox SK 400 II

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You need to turn off exposure simulation in live view.**

Exposure simulation can only show you what the image would look like without flash, because the flash burst isn't in the scene until you take the shot.

Since it's very common to underexpose or even kill the ambient with flash photography, most cameras allow you to turn off exposure simulation when using a flash for this reason, and will just try to give you the best live view image possible, without trying to simulate the exposure settings you're using, so that you have a bright enough view to judge focus and composition by.  On a Z6 II, you're looking for [the **d9** Custom function](https://download.nikonimglib.com/archive4/7uiGZ0074QAJ05k6lw523d1cQF97/Z7IIZ6IIRM_(En)05.pdf#page=444) to turn off **Apply Settings in Live View**.

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt reply! And sharing the exact cause and solution.

Answer (score -3):

I'm just checking but are you using a flash meter ? It's possible  to do without one but very hit and miss.

Comment: Whether or not you use a flash meter does not impact the image in live view.  This does not answer the question.

Comment: Please use comments if you try to clarifiy a question. The answer box is reserved for answers only. However you comment also does not fit the question, as live view with strobes is not depending on any flash power setting.